# Improving grunt setup and speed

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am new to grunt and I have a simple grunt setup that will compile my sass and jade and auto reload my browser. This configuration is not very fast, I have to wait 5-7 seconds to detect changes and auto reload. Is there any way of improving the speed?

My gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        jade: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    pretty: true,
                    nospawn: false
                },

                files: {
                    'index.html' : 'src/index.jade'
                }
            }
        },

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded',
                    nospawn: false
                },

                files: {
                    'build/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.sass'
                }
            },

            fin: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    nospawn: false
                },

                files: {
                    'build/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.sass'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            jade: {
                files: 'src/**/*.jade',
                tasks: ['jade']
            },

            css: {
                files: 'src/sass/**/*.sass',
                tasks: ['sass:dist']
            },

            options: {
                livereload: true,
                nospawn: false
            }
        },

        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 9000,
                    base: '.',
                    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
                    protocol: 'http',
                    livereload: true,
                    open: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'newer:watch']);
};
```

Comment: Try without the `grunt-newer plugin`

Comment: I put the grunt-newer plugin to make it faster but I have the same speeds with or without it.